# How to get a bash instance with loaded default profiles within objective-C

Tags: cocoa, macos, bash, rvm

**Problem:**
I want to be able to run a bash instance from my cocoa application (OS X) with all the normal profiles loaded (~/.bash_profile, etc). I **don't** want to load the profiles manually since I want to have a default bash instance that is exactly the same as one you would get by firing terminal. From there, I'd like to retrieve some pre-defined environment variable (Ruby version manager's variables).

**What I've tried:**
I've already tried some solutions with no success. Let me list them here:

1. NSTask
2. system() call

for every solutions I tried to execute "/bin/sh -l" to have a bash instance loaded as the current username... unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean execute how ? I execute the program as the user who launched the program, I'm not forking a process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `bash` as `sh`, it runs in a compatibility mode where it doesn't read `.bash_profile`.  If you want to run `bash` then run `/bin/bash` (or if you want other people to use your application, make sure you account for whatever shell the user has selected.)

Comment: I'm trying it tomorrow. It seems to make a lot of sense!

Comment: It worked. It's still not exactly what I want, but this is answering the question above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line option '`--login`' to tell `bash` to behave as a login shell.

Classically, a shell would act as a login shell if the basename of its `argv[0]` started with a dash.

You might be able to get the required effect with:

```
bash --login -c 'echo $RUBY_VARIABLE_OF_INTEREST'
```

If you are doing this with `popen()`, you can read the output from the shell.